# How to get Docker Registry for Dedicated Server on OVH

Tags: docker, docker-registry, ovh

I have added dedicated server on OVH and now I need to push docker image on OVH but I do not know where does Docker Registry exist on OVH and how to activate it.

Please let me know if someone is aware of it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Docker Registry Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/). 
Here are the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

As far as I know, OVH does not yet offer a Docker Registry.

Comment: When I searched on Google, I could see OVH-docker-registry link as follows but I am not able to access it, but they might have provided this support then.

"OVH Docker Registry | OVH Labs
https://labs.ovh.com/ovh-docker-registry"